# Evaluating $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there a way to solve $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $ without relying on test such as the ratio test. Possibly solve it using algebra and integrals?

Comment: Thats $e^x$ expansion.

Comment: As Gautam Shenoy says, it is $e^x$ but if you are asking this we need your definition of $e^x$.  There are a number of routes that lead the same place.

Comment: The ratio test only tells you that it converges, not what it converges to, so if you want a value you need something else.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: Very similar question from yesterday: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237261/find-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Gautam Shenoy points out in the comments, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is $e^x$.  One way to see this with derivatives is by noting that term-by-term differentiation gives
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
after reindexing in the last step.  In other words, it satisfies the differential equation $f' = f$.  By checking with the initial condition $x=0$, the sum must be $e^x$.

(The unique solution to $f' = f$ with $f(0) = 1$ is one of the definitions of $e^x$.  Another definition of $e^x$ is as the power series given.  If you're using a different definition, there may be a little more work to do to use this fact.)

Comment: Im sorry what type of definition are there for e^x. I though it was a standard function? Btw, cool way of showing it converges to e^x by noting that it matches the differentiate property of e^x.

Comment: Even the standard functions have to be defined!  You can define $e^x$ as the unique function satisfying $f'=f, f(0)=1$, you can define $e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$, you can define $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$, you can define $e^x$ as the number $y$ such that $\int_1^y\frac{du}{u} = x$, ... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function

Comment: @Neal But these definitions are not equivalent. If you define $e^x$ one way, you should prove the others.